# What is the opposite of "hunger level"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am creating a computer game in which the character needs to consume food in order to not starve to death. In the game I can display the level of how much food the character currently needs via "hunger level" - the higher this value, the more desperately the character needs food.

But what I want now is to turn that around, so that this level tells how full the stomach of the character is. In German we have a word for that, "Sättigung", which means how full my stomach is (or better: how full it feels to me), it is basically the opposite of hunger.

Is there a similar word in English, which means exactly that, the opposite of hunger? It might be something like "saturation", but from what I can tell this word is usually used in a technical context, like in "the saturation of a color".

Can I use that "saturation" to describe the opposite of hunger of a human or animal, or is there a better word for that?

Comment: Hello, Matthias. If I close-vote here, the question might actually close (I'm never sure). But ELU expects a certain amount of reasonable research. Did you look up antonyms of 'hunger' in a thesaurus?

Comment: Should this be here or on learners?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: If you have the ability to vote to close, it will take 5 such votes to close a question, and 5 votes to reopen a closed question. (Two exceptions: 1. Diamond mods can single-handedly close/reopen a question, and 2. [If you have a gold "tag badge", you can instantly close a question with that badge as a duplicate of another question, or reopen such a question that was closed as a duplicate.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)

Comment: You could also consider "food level" as an alternative.

Comment: You may be interested in how the game Don't Starve handles it. They call it [Hunger](https://dontstarve.fandom.com/wiki/Hunger), but the in-game representation is graphical, showing a meter over a stomach that can go from full to empty and shriveled up.

Comment: "Naming things" is generally off-topic sorry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because choosing names for things is off-topic according to our Help Center.

Comment: @tchrist, despite the underlying motivation, the question is less about choosing a name and more about choosing a word. The question asks *"Is there a similar word in English, which means exactly that, the opposite of hunger?"*. Every paragraph contains a similar request. In the Help Center, an acceptable type of question is: "Word choice and usage".

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think the apter word is 'satiety' than 'saturation' in the OP's context.

> **[satiety](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/satiety)**
>
> the state of being completely satisfied, especially with food or
>   pleasure, so that you could not have any more.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97530/discussion-on-answer-by-mahmud-koya-what-is-the-opposite-of-hunger-level).

Answer (score 30):

"Hunger Level" includes everything from starvation to satiety.

If you imagine a [health bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_(gaming)) in a video game, a low hunger level indicates that you're good for now (you're not hungry). A high level indicates starvation and the need to focus on refueling.

So there's really no opposite to "Hunger Level". It covers everything from one end to the other.

However, if you want an opposite to "hunger" in this context, then consider:

### fullness

*I ate already. I'm full.*

*My stomach is so full. I feel like I'm about to burst.*

The health bar indicator for "Fullness" would be the reverse of "Hunger", which may be more intuitive for a video game.

Also, a video game with a "Fullness" meter wouldn't distract the player. A term like "Satiety" may hold their attention, as they ponder the meaning and pronunciation.

Comment: I totally agree with "A term like "Satiety" may hold their attention, as they ponder the meaning and pronunciation." +1

Comment: Part of this answer is back to front, a low hunger level would indicate you don't need to eat, a high hunger level would indicate "I am very hungry" and should eat soon.

Comment: @ChrisCooper, good point. Answer revised. Thank you.

Comment: I disagree with @ChrisCooper's suggestion, all the games I can think of with a hunger meter have full meter = satiated, low meter = hungry. See: The Sims, Minecraft, various survival games, etc. A low meter in a video game pretty much always means "this thing needs my attention".

Comment: @Pyritie then I'd contend it's not a measure of hunger, it's a measure of satiety. Purely in terms of English it'd be weird to suggest that a high value on a hunger meter meant you weren't hungry.

Comment: @ChrisCooper It might not be entirely logical but that's just what I've seen in video games.

Comment: It would need to be a two-way bar, with hunger in one direction, being over-stuffed (as after Thanksgiving dinner) in the other, and the midpoint being optimum.

Comment: I'd agree that there's no need to reverse the meter.  Also, you don't need the word "Level".  Just go with "Hunger".  That will be pretty much universally understood by all English-speaking players.

Comment: He's not asking for a second indicator, he wants to invert his current indicator. OP currently has a bar where full is bad and empty is good. That's not terribly intuitive in a video game, especially if it's beside other bars that work the other way. That's presumably why he wants to reverse the direction of the bar, and in my opinion probably a good idea in most situations.

Comment: @Zeus, I removed that phrase. Answer revised. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeus: But if you're trying to be realistic, full can be as bad for both physical activity and mental acuity as hunger.

Answer (score 23):

I am a German native speaker as well, so I have little feeling for the frequency of use. I did find the words

> ### satiety
>
> the quality or state of being fed or gratified to or beyond capacity, surfeit, fullness

as well as

> ### satiation
>
> the act of completely satisfying yourself or a need, especially with food or pleasure

The former seems to be more fitting in your context, yet both of them are slightly more medical and less common in everyday language, see [here](https://healthyeating.sfgate.com/foods-high-satiation-3799.html) for example.

Sources: [Satiety](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/satiety), [Satiation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/satiation)

Comment: To me (native to UK), _satiation_ sounds slightly more natural... "_Satiation level: 86%_" etc.

Comment: I agree with @TripeHound (I'm a Canadian) - but that might just be because ADOM uses "satiation" as one of the hunger levels.

Comment: If we are providing this sort of data, to me (native to the US) *"satiety"* is the much more natural choice.  I would have been thinking that *"satiation"* was neologism if I were to have heard it in conversation.

Comment: For yet another anecdote, I’m from the US (Southwestern) and “satiation” sounds pretty natural, whereas “satiety” sounds weird.

Comment: "Satiation" / "satiation level" sounds more natural to me as well (native to Australia).

Answer (score 8):

One possible option is **energy**, or **energy level**. It is not a direct answer for the question of the opposite of hunger, but energy levels are definitely affected by what we eat. In a game it would make fairly intuitive sense that eating foods restores your energy meter.

Answer (score 5):

For a computer game, *Satiety* is going to sound weird as it's an uncommon and formal word. *Food* is not a good word because it sounds like you're carrying it around with you uneaten. I think **Nutrition** would be a good name for your level indicator. Nutrition is not a feeling, but it expresses the meaning that you want.

Comment: I work in computer games and agree that "Satiety", while technically correct, is not a common enough word for the context. If "anti-hunger" is the *only* thing determining the player's energy level then I'd use "Energy" or similar - it conveys the *impact* it has on the user most clearly. Otherwise, if there's something else that has an impact (e.g. some games have separate "stamina" or "damage" attributes), and you really do just need to convey "fullness-of-stomach" with this term, then this answer, "Nutrition", is the best so far. Something like "Fullness" could be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of the computer role-playing game that I grew up with, *Ancient Domains of Mystery*, or *ADOM*, I heard this as being called your "*satiation level*", and your German word feels like it has the same historic root.

So I would go with that: **satiation level**, especially considering you are already using the term "level", and hence this mirrors your proposed construction exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some suggestions you could use -

**1.** fulfillment (-level)

> - a feeling of happiness and satisfaction.

<sup><sup>Source: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/fulfilment</sup></sup>

**2.** satisfaction (-level)

> - fulfillment of one's wishes, expectations, or needs, or the pleasure derived from this.

<sup><sup>Source: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/satisfaction</sup></sup>

**3.** repletion (-level)

> - Repletion is a condition of being completely full of something. Repletion is experienced by people who are full or satisfied by the
>     amount of food they've eaten, but it can also describe other kinds of
>     fullness.

<sup><sup>Source: https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/repletion</sup></sup>

**4.** surfeit (-level)

> - to indulge to satiety in a gratification (such as indulgence of the appetite or senses)

<sup><sup>Source: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/surfeit</sup></sup>

**5.** fullness (-level)

> - the quality or state of being full

<sup><sup>Source: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/fullness</sup></sup>

Comment: Please cite sources for your dictionary quotes. A simple link and formatting the quote using the `>` is generally accepted here.

Comment: @JJJ - I have edited my answer according to your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your post to say why each of those makes sense here. Answers without reasons are not answers, and merely Let Me Thesaurus That For You answers are even worse.

Answer (score 1):

I have always had this same question, and **feed** worked for me.

[Definition from dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/feed)

> ***noun***
>
> - food, especially for farm animals, as cattle, horses or chickens.
> - an allowance, portion, or supply of such food.
> - *Informal*. a meal, especially a lavish one.
> - the material, or the amount of it, so fed or supplied.

It might not be a perfect word, but its suitable for games.

Comment: Did you mean to write *food* not *feed*?

Comment: @tchrist Nope, I meant *feed*

Answer (score 0):

The game Nethack has been using "**Satiated**" to mean that your character is full, to the point of having eaten a little too much. That's the clue given to the player to stop eating things or suffer further ill effects. It's described [here](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Nutrition#Hunger_status) with *nutrition* being the internal variable and *hunger* shows what the player would see about it (they don't get the exact number).

Instead of using a single word, you might consider several words on the spectrum of hunger and fullness. In the Nethack example they use "Starved" to show your character died of hunger and "Oversatiated" to describe the, rather graphic, situation of consuming so much food that one's airway is blocked, and thus experiences suffocation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy term for you, Matthias. It may not be a perfect one, but I feel it fits:
'Feeding Level" 
(When babies are 'hungry', we 'feed'them, don't we?) Maybe other members have better terms. Love to learn them, too.

Answer (score -4):

**Stomach-Level**

Stomach-level suggests the actual level to which the stomach is full. Native English speakers will imagine the stomach as a pot or container which is literally full ‘up to here’ - full to a certain point.

Satiety is a correct term but may not be understood by all users as it’s a rather advanced word. Satisfaction is a bit abstract and not so much to do with literally ‘how full you are’ but rather the pleasing effect that the food had on you.

If you want to use stomach level, it could also be used for hunger level. One term could fulfil both functions.  Then if hungry, it might also say ‘hungry’ or if full, it could say ‘full’ or ‘sated’ (sated is also a bit of an advanced word). Or for very full it could say ‘stuffed’, which is humorous.